# ¿Por qué mi socket de cliente no recibe bien el archivo que le envía el servidor UDP?

Tags: python, socket, connection, tcpudp

Hice sockets UDP en python, y necesito implementar el CRC para que los archivos se envíen correctamente, los códigos son los siguientes:
**Servidor (Envía)**

```
import socket
import time
import base64
import sys
def xor(a, b): 

    # initialize result 
    result = [] 

    for i in range(1, len(b)): 
        if a[i] == b[i]: 
            result.append('0') 
        else: 
            result.append('1') 

    return ''.join(result) 


# Performs Modulo-2 division 
def mod2div(divident, divisor): 

    # Number of bits to be XORed at a time. 
    pick = len(divisor) 

    tmp = divident[0 : pick] 

    while pick < len(divident): 

        if tmp[0] == '1': 

            tmp = xor(divisor, tmp) + divident[pick] 

        else: # If leftmost bit is '0' 

            tmp = xor('0'*pick, tmp) + divident[pick] 

        # increment pick to move further 
        pick += 1

    if tmp[0] == '1': 
        tmp = xor(divisor, tmp) 
    else: 
        tmp = xor('0'*pick, tmp) 

    checkword = tmp 
    return checkword 

def encodeData(data, key): 
    l_key = len(key)
    # Appends n-1 zeroes at end of data 
    appended_data = data + '0'*(l_key-1) 
    remainder = mod2div(appended_data, key) 

    # Append remainder in the original data 
    codeword = data + remainder 
    return codeword 
def decodeData(data, key): 

    l_key = len(key) 

    # Appends n-1 zeroes at end of data 
    appended_data = data + '0'*(l_key-1)
    remainder = mod2div(appended_data, key) 

    return remainder
def CRC_ENCODE(datos):
    datos=''.join(format(ord(c), 'b') for c in datos)
    datosN=encodeData(datos, "1001")
    return datosN

def CompruebaMensaje(datos, destino):
    datos=CRC_ENCODE(datos)
    sock.sendto(datos.encode('utf-8'), destino)

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
BUFFER_SIZE=1024
poly="1001"
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.1.100', 10000)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
comando=data
if(comando.decode('utf-8')=="no"):
    print("Entrando en modo eco")
    while True:
        print('\nEsperando el siguiente mensaje')
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("El cliente dice: ",data.decode('utf-8'))
        if data:
            entregado="Recibi el dato"
            crc_code=CRC_ENCODE(entregado)
            mandar = entregado + '}' + crc_code
            sock.sendto(mandar.encode('utf-8'), address)
        if(data.decode('utf-8')=="exit"):
            break
if(comando.decode('utf-8')=="si"):
    print("Entrando en modo descarga")
    archivo, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("El cliente quiere descargar: ",archivo.decode('utf-8'))
    local=archivo.decode('utf-8')
    f = open(local, errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')
    data=f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("El tamaño del archivo es: ",len(data))
    while(data):
        crc_code=CRC_ENCODE(data)
        print("El tamaño del crc es: ",len(crc_code))
        sock.sendto(crc_code.encode('utf-8'), address)
        #time.sleep(0.0001)
        sock.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), address)
        seguimos, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("El cliente dice: ",seguimos.decode('utf-8'))
        if(seguimos.decode('utf-8')=="ok"):
            #sock.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), address)
           # time.sleep(0.1)
            data=f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not data:
                print("Archivo enviado con exito")
                sock.sendto("EOF".encode('utf-8'), address)
                sock.close()
                f.close()
                break
        else:
            print("Error al enviar el archivo")
            error, add = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE) 
            #sock.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), address)
```

**Cliente (Recibe)**

```
import socket
import select
import sys
separador= " "

def xor(a, b): 

    # initialize result 
    result = [] 

    # Traverse all bits, if bits are 
    # same, then XOR is 0, else 1 
    for i in range(1, len(b)): 
        if a[i] == b[i]: 
            result.append('0') 
        else: 
            result.append('1') 

    return ''.join(result) 


# Performs Modulo-2 division 
def mod2div(divident, divisor): 

    # Number of bits to be XORed at a time. 
    pick = len(divisor) 

    # Slicing the divident to appropriate 
    # length for particular step 
    tmp = divident[0 : pick] 

    while pick < len(divident): 

        if tmp[0] == '1': 

            # replace the divident by the result 
            # of XOR and pull 1 bit down 
            tmp = xor(divisor, tmp) + divident[pick] 

        else: # If leftmost bit is '0' 
            # If the leftmost bit of the dividend (or the 
            # part used in each step) is 0, the step cannot 
            # use the regular divisor; we need to use an 
            # all-0s divisor. 
            tmp = xor('0'*pick, tmp) + divident[pick]

        # increment pick to move further 
        pick += 1

    # For the last n bits, we have to carry it out 
    # normally as increased value of pick will cause 
    # Index Out of Bounds. 
    if tmp[0] == '1': 
        tmp = xor(divisor, tmp) 
    else: 
        tmp = xor('0'*pick, tmp) 

    checkword = tmp 
    return checkword 

# Function used at the receiver side to decode 
# data received by sender 
def encodeData(data, key): 
    l_key = len(key)
    # Appends n-1 zeroes at end of data 
    appended_data = data + '0'*(l_key-1) 
    remainder = mod2div(appended_data, key) 

    # Append remainder in the original data 
    codeword = data + remainder 
    return codeword 
def decodeData(data, key): 

    l_key = len(key) 

    # Appends n-1 zeroes at end of data 
    appended_data = data + '0'*(l_key-1)
    remainder = mod2div(appended_data, key) 

    return remainder
def CRC_ENCODE(datos):
    datos=''.join(format(ord(c), 'b') for c in datos)
    datosN=decodeData(datos, "1001")
    return datosN

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
BUFFER_SIZE=2048
server_address = ('192.168.1.100', 10000)
message = "¿Quieres descargar algo?"
print(message)
r=input()
sock.sendto(r.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
if(r=="no"):
    # Send data
    while(message!="exit"):
        message=input("Ingresa el mensaje a enviar: ")
        sent = sock.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
        # Receive response
        datos, server = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        datos=datos.decode('utf-8')
        datos, crc = datos.split(',')
        verif = decodeData(crc, "1001")
        if(verif=="000"):
            print("Mensaje del servidor: ", datos)
        else:
            print("Error en el mensaje")
if(r=="si"):
    archivo=input("Ingresa el nombre del archivo a descargar: ")
    sent = sock.sendto(archivo.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
    arch2="copia-"+archivo
    f = open(arch2, "wb")
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(7000)
    print("El tamaño del crc es: ", len(data))
    while(data):
        verif = decodeData(data.decode('utf-8'), "1001")
        if(verif=="000"):
            datos, addres=sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
            print("El tamaño del archivo es: ", len(datos))
            f.write(datos)
            sock.sendto("ok".encode('utf-8'), server_address)
            if(data=="EOF".encode('utf-8')):
                print("Archivo recibido con exito")
                f.close()
                sock.close()
                break
        
        else:
            print("Error en el mensaje")
            sock.sendto("error".encode('utf-8'), server_address)
            #data, addr = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
            #f.write(data)
        data, addres=sock.recvfrom(7000)
```

Lo que pasa es que, sin implementar el CRC, sirve perfectamente el envío de archivos, es decir, llega con algunas imperfecciones o pérdidas de datos, pero es una característica del UDP, para eso implemento el CRC, para que lleguen de manera correcta los archivos. Pero mi código me genera problemas, al momento de enviar el archivo, llega con mucha pérdida de información, es decir, si el archivo original pesa 2.2 mb, el que llega pesa 1.7 mb. Creo que estoy haciendo bien el CRC, ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Yo creo que para enviar un archivo debes ocupar TCP

Comment: He leido que udp es mas rapido, pero con el costo de que "se pierden paquetes". Creo que Yussef tiene razón.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en como chequeas el EOF en el cliente. El mensaje vienen sin CRC.

La forma correcta es chequear la condición antes de revisar el CRC y grabar en el archivo.

En *cliente.py*, hay que modificar el contenido del ciclo `while (data):`

```
if (r == "si"):
    archivo = input("Ingresa el nombre del archivo a descargar: ")
    sent = sock.sendto(archivo.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
    arch2 = "copia-" + archivo
    f = open(arch2, "wb")
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(7000)
    print("El tamaño del crc es: ", len(data))
    while (data):
        if (data == "EOF".encode('utf-8')):
            print("Archivo recibido con exito")
            f.close()
            sock.close()
            break

        verif = decodeData(data.decode('utf-8'), "1001")
        if (verif == "000"):
            datos, addres = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
            print("El tamaño del archivo es: ", len(datos))
            f.write(datos)
            sock.sendto("ok".encode('utf-8'), server_address)
        else:
            print("Error en el mensaje")
            sock.sendto("error".encode('utf-8'), server_address)
            # data, addr = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
            # f.write(data)
```